# WSO2 Publisher- Cannot read property 'paths' of null error on Proceeding to Implementing stage in Api creation

Tags: websocket, wso2, wso2-api-manager, ibm-api-management

We have been using wso2 api manager(v 2.1.0) for a long time in our project. Addition of Rest api is working fine in publisher. But we are getting error while adding a new Websocket api. APi is getting created . But while we are going from DESIGN phase to IMPLEMENT phase , getting an error like

```
Cannot read property 'paths' of null
```

[image: The button 'Next:Implement' is clicked]

[image]

What might be the issue ? I am implementing websocket api for the first time